# Bypass the proxy using TcpClient

Tags: c#, networking, proxy, tcpclient

I'm trying to write a local proxy application. I know how proxy applications work in theory. 
I've done everything related to handle incoming connections. But the problem is how should I send request which client requested to specified Url. When I try to create a connection with `TcpClient` to specified Url and port, it throws following exception :

> No such host is known

**Edit :** I think I should bypass the proxy something like FireFox is doing even system proxy set.

Any idea will be helpful.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this help? http://alandean.blogspot.co.uk/2010/06/routing-tcpclient-http-requests-through.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These links might be of help:

- http://www.replicator.org/journal/201011170043-net-connecting-a-tcpclient-through-an-http-proxy-with-authentication
- http://alandean.blogspot.co.uk/2010/06/routing-tcpclient-http-requests-through.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply, That first link helped me. I changed some lines of code and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Based on colinsmith provided links, I've done to bypass proxy using TcpClient. Here is how I did that :

```
    public static TcpClient CreateTcpClient(string url)
    {
        var webRequest = WebRequest.Create(url);
        webRequest.Proxy = null;

        var webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();
        var resposeStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();

        const BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance;

        var rsType = resposeStream.GetType();
        var connectionProperty = rsType.GetProperty("Connection", flags);

        var connection = connectionProperty.GetValue(resposeStream, null);
        var connectionType = connection.GetType();
        var networkStreamProperty = connectionType.GetProperty("NetworkStream", flags);

        var networkStream = networkStreamProperty.GetValue(connection, null);
        var nsType = networkStream.GetType();
        var socketProperty = nsType.GetProperty("Socket", flags);
        var socket = (Socket)socketProperty.GetValue(networkStream, null);

        return new TcpClient { Client = socket };
    }
```

Hope this help for others.