# How to use Proxy with TcpClient.ConnectAsync()?

Tags: c#, .net, networking, proxy, tcpclient

HTTP proxy support in .NET does not actually support the lower level classes like TcpClient or Socket. But I want to connect a TCPServer (ip, port) through HTTP proxy that support 'CONNECT' command.

So I need to do the following steps:

1. Connect to proxy.
2. Send `CONNECT Host:Port HTTP/1.1<CR><LF>`
3. Send `<CR><LF>`
4. Wait for a line of response. If it contains `HTTP/1.X 200`, the connection is successful.
5. Read further lines of response until receive an empty line.
6. It's connected to the outside world through a proxy. Any data exchange as posssible with proxy.

Actually I do this without proxy

```
    TcpClient _client;
    NetworkStream _stream;

    public static async Task<bool> ConnectAsync(string hostname, int port)
    {
        _client = new TcpClient();
        await _client.ConnectAsync(hostname, port).ConfigureAwait(false);
        _stream = conn._client.GetStream();

        ..... Do some stuff

        // Connexion OK
        return true;
    }
```

How can use proxy and credentials before connecting TcpClient?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I find a solution base on [.NET: Connecting a TcpClient through an HTTP proxy with authentication](http://www.replicator.org/journal/201011170043-net-connecting-a-tcpclient-through-an-http-proxy-with-authentication) and [Bypass the proxy using TcpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710251/bypass-the-proxy-using-tcpclient)

```
TcpClient _client;
NetworkStream _stream;

public TcpClient ProxyTcpClient(string targetHost, int targetPort, string httpProxyHost, int httpProxyPort, string proxyUserName, string proxyPassword)
{
        const BindingFlags Flags = BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance;
        Uri proxyUri = new UriBuilder
        {
            Scheme = Uri.UriSchemeHttp,
            Host = httpProxyHost,
            Port = httpProxyPort
        }.Uri;
        Uri targetUri = new UriBuilder
        {
             Scheme = Uri.UriSchemeHttp,
             Host = targetHost,
             Port = targetPort
        }.Uri;

        WebProxy webProxy = new WebProxy(proxyUri, true);
        webProxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(proxyUserName, proxyPassword);
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(targetUri);
        request.Proxy = webProxy;
        request.Method = "CONNECT";
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        Type responseType = responseStream.GetType();
        PropertyInfo connectionProperty = responseType.GetProperty("Connection", Flags);
        var connection = connectionProperty.GetValue(responseStream, null);
        Type connectionType = connection.GetType();
        PropertyInfo networkStreamProperty = connectionType.GetProperty("NetworkStream", Flags);
        NetworkStream networkStream = (NetworkStream)networkStreamProperty.GetValue(connection, null);
        Type nsType = networkStream.GetType();
        PropertyInfo socketProperty = nsType.GetProperty("Socket", Flags);
        Socket socket = (Socket)socketProperty.GetValue(networkStream, null);

        return new TcpClient { Client = socket };
}

public static async Task<bool> ConnectAsync(string hostname, int port)
{
        _client = ProxyTcpClient("IPTargetHost", 1234, "IPProxyHost", 5678, "Userproxy", "Userppwd");
        _stream = conn._client.GetStream();

        ..... Do some stuff

        // Connexion OK
        return true;
}
```

Comment: This solution seems to be ab it hacky... is there any other way to set the proxy without using reflection?

Comment: This seems to not work using .net core. Does anybody have a solution for .net core?

Answer (score 4):

We have managed to implement it using .Net's `Socket`. Nuget package is called [Filemail.ProxiedTcpClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Filemail.ProxiedTcpClient). The code is pretty simple:

```
public static TcpClient CreateProxied(Uri proxy, Uri destination)
{
    var socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

    socket.Connect(proxy.Host, proxy.Port);

    var connectMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"CONNECT {destination.Host}:{destination.Port} HTTP/1.1{Environment.NewLine}{Environment.NewLine}");
    socket.Send(connectMessage);

    byte[] receiveBuffer = new byte[1024];
    var received = socket.Receive(receiveBuffer);

    var response = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveBuffer, 0, received);

    if (!response.Contains("200 OK"))
    {
        throw new Exception($"Error connecting to proxy server {destination.Host}:{destination.Port}. Response: {response}");
    }

    return new TcpClient
    {
        Client = socket
    };
}
```

Contribute here: https://github.com/filemail/ProxiedTcpClient

Comment: I had to set the Host in the connect message to make it work using a proxy behind the proxy. `var connectMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"CONNECT {destinationHost}:{destinationPort} HTTP/1.1{Environment.NewLine}Host: {destinationHost}:{destinationPort}{Environment.NewLine}{Environment.NewLine}");`

Comment: Also some connects can answer with `Connection Established` instead of `OK`. The if statement would become: `!response.Contains("200 OK", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) && !response.Contains("200 Connection Established", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)`

Answer (score 2):

To extend [Rychu's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61953143/9033228) answer if the proxy requires basic auth, add the header to the connection message

```
var auth = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{proxy.Login}:{proxy.Password}"));
var connectMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"CONNECT {host}:{port} HTTP/1.1\nProxy-Authorization: Basic {auth}\n\n");
socket.Send(connectMessage);
```