# Connect TcpClient through Fiddler proxy

Tags: c#, tcp, proxy

How can I use a Fiddler proxy with a TcpClient?  The answer on this similar question did not work for me: [How to use Proxy with TcpClient.ConnectAsync()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35066981/how-to-use-proxy-with-tcpclient-connectasync)

```
var client = new Pop3Client();
var tcpClient = new TcpClient(hostname, port);
var sslStream = new SslStream(tcpClient.GetStream());
sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(hostname);
client.Connect(sslStream);
```

Comment: *"...did not work for me:..."* - this information is not really helpful. It does not say what exactly did not work, i.e. did you get any error messages anywhere, did you try to debug the issue to make sure that it actually tries to do the intended thing (i.e. create tunnel using CONNECT) etc and at which step it failed.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich When client.Connect(sslStream) is called it hangs for about 60 seconds then I receive a PopServerNotAvailableException: 'Server is not available'.  But I know the server is available (I can connect to it with another overload of client.Connect, but I need it to go through a proxy), so it's not very helpful.  Also I can see the CONNECT request in Fiddler with a 200 response, so not really sure why I'm having problems.

Comment: So you can see the CONNECT with the 200 response in Fiddler. Can you also see the following data, i.e. that your client attempts to do a TLS handshake (ClientHello) and if it gets a response? And are you sure that you connect to the correct port within the CONNECT command, i.e. use pop3s (port 995) and not pop3 (port 110)? Could you provide a packet capture (for example at cloudshark.org)? The reason I ask is that a different method to use a proxy might result in the same problems since not the method was wrong but other things.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response.  I started WireShark then ran the code, here is the capture.  https://www.cloudshark.org/captures/4c510f1142e7

And yeah I am sure I am connecting to 995.  P.S. I did not see a TLS handshake in Fiddler, only the CONNECT request with 200 response.

Comment: The file is not accessible for me. Please make it public.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I have never used cloudshark.org...sorry.  I found out how to make it public though, check again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182986/discussion-between-steffen-ullrich-and-david-stampher).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some discussion it turned out that the code to create a connection through a proxy which was referenced in the question actually worked, but

- SSL decryption need to be off in Fiddler.
  Otherwise Fiddler will not pass the original TLS handshake through but will create one between Fiddler and Server and another one between Client and Fiddler, where the last one has a certificate created by Fiddler. The client will usually not trust this certificate by default and thus fail the TLS handshake.
  Moreover, Fiddler expects the traffic inside the TLS connection to be HTTP, i.e. the client sends a HTTP request and the server sends a HTTP response back. POP3 works differently by having both a different message syntax and by having the server start with sending and not the client.
- It really has to be `client.Connect(sslStream)` as shown in the question and not something like `client.Connect(tcpStream)` as the OP had in its actual code. In the last case the client will just try to read the encrypted data from the connection and thus fail.