# How to connect through the proxy with .Net/Mono TCP/UDP Socket?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, networking, proxy

We are using C# `Socket` in Unity to connect to our server. Using proxy is crucial for our use case, unfortunately there is no direct support for proxy in `Socket`. We are using both TCP and UDP sockets at the same time to exchange data between our app and the server.

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35066981/how-to-use-proxy-with-tcpclient-connectasync/) question I'm able to connect through the proxy with first TCP socket, but when I try to connect through the same proxy with second UDP socket, I receive this exception on line `socket.Receive(receiveBuffer)`:

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
ErrorCode = 10054
SocketErrorCode = ConnectionReset
```

Does it means that the first TCP ws closed because ther can be only one connection at the same time?

I'm using `Fiddler` to test this scenario. I do not see the second UDP connection in its log.

Is it possible to connect through single proxy with more than one socket from the same app (process)?
Is there some settings in Fiddler that should be changed? Am I missing something?

My simplified code:

```
class ConnectorExample
{
    public class ProxyConfig
    {
        public string server; // http://127.0.0.1:8888
        public string username;
        public string password;

        public Uri serverUri => new Uri(server);
    }

    void Connect(IPAddress ipAddress, int tcpPort, int udpPort, ProxyConfig proxyConfig)
    {
        IPEndPoint remoteTcpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, tcpPort);
        IPEndPoint remoteUdpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, udpPort);

        Socket tcpSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        Socket udpSocket = new Socket(tcpSocket.AddressFamily, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);

        // TCP socket
        ConnectThroughProxy(proxyConfig, tcpSocket, remoteTcpEndPoint);

        // UDP Socket
        // Bind UDP to a free port
        udpSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(((IPEndPoint) tcpSocket.LocalEndPoint).Address, 0));
        ConnectThroughProxy(proxyConfig, udpSocket, remoteUdpEndPoint);
    }

    // Returns true if connection through the proxy succeeded
    private bool ConnectThroughProxy(ProxyConfig proxyConfig, Socket socket, IPEndPoint destination)
    {
        Uri proxyUri = proxyConfig.serverUri;
        string username = proxyConfig.username;
        string password = proxyConfig.password;

        // Connect to the proxy
        socket.Connect(proxyUri.Host, proxyUri.Port);

        // Authentication
        string auth = string.Empty;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(username) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
        {
            string credentials = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{username}:{password}"));
            auth = $"Proxy-Authorization: Basic {credentials}";
        }

        // Connect to the destination
        // string connectString = $"CONNECT {destination.Address}:{destination.Port} HTTP/1.1{Environment.NewLine}{auth}{Environment.NewLine}{Environment.NewLine}";
        string hostAddress = $"{destination.Address}:{destination.Port}";
        string connectString = $"CONNECT {destination.Address}:{destination.Port} HTTP/1.1{Environment.NewLine}Host: {hostAddress}{Environment.NewLine}{auth}{Environment.NewLine}{Environment.NewLine}";
        byte[] connectMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(connectString);
        socket.Send(connectMessage);

        byte[] receiveBuffer = new byte[1024];
        int received = socket.Receive(receiveBuffer); // Exception for second UDP socket

        string response = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveBuffer, 0, received);
        // Response content sample:
        // HTTP/1.1 200 Connection Established

        // TODO: Should we check for string: "HTTP/1.1 200" ? Checking just "200" seems to be quite weak check.
        bool connected = response.Contains("200");
        return connected;
    }
}
```

EDIT:
Perhaps the correct question is: **Is it possible to use proxy for UDP connections?**

Comment: TCP and UDP are separate protocols, and TCP port `12345` is not UDP port `12345`. They bot use a 16-bit number for an address (port), but they are not the same ports. "_An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host._ means that the remote host TCP sent a RST for some reason. [RFC 792](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc793#section-3.4) explains all the reasons for a RST: "_As a general rule, reset (RST) must be sent whenever a segment arrives which apparently is not intended for the current connection. A reset must not be sent if it is not clear that this is the case._"

Comment: Perhaps the correct question is: Is it possible to use proxy for UDP connections?

Comment: You can use proxies for UDP, e.g. using the SOCKS5 protocol. Your proxy looks like a HTTP proxy, which cannot do such a thing. Samples: https://blog.zhaytam.com/2019/11/15/socks5-a-net-core-implementation-from-scratch/ ,  https://github.com/ThrDev/Socks5