# Use .net core proxy server code for any TCP connection

Tags: c#, .net-core, networking, proxy, tcpclient

I want to tunnel/run my own protocol over an HTTP proxy using the connect method. Implementing this correctly including ntlm proxy authentication or proxy.pac support is very hard and I'd like to use the HTTP stack from .net core.

In the past this worked with .net framework using code like in

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35090558/20088

however in .net core I get an exception "CONNECT request must contain Host header.", even if I set the host header.

Did anybody manage to use the .net core http stack for this purpose?